# Linq, why is setting parameter to null returns all rows in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently studying asp.net mvc 3 and I'm wathing plural sight's course video, and I'm curious about a certain code:

Here it is:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string state)
        {
            //var restaurants = context.Restaurants.ToList();
            var restaurants = from r in context.Restaurants
                              where r.Address.State == state || (state == null)
                              select r;
            return View(restaurants);
        }
```

Obviously the state parameter is used to filter the query, so if state = CA, then only rows with a state value of CA will be retrieved, the the part that I don't get is why is that adding || state == null allows the query to get all rows.

Here's another one that is quite similar to above code:

```
var students = from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
```

In this one it checks if the paramter is empty or null and then sets a different query by adding a where clause.

So what is actually happening when I add that state == null

Sir/Ma'am, your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Comment: It's an OR.  If `state == null`, it fulfills one side of the OR.  If you're wondering why it's there, it's probably there to allow the user to not select a state at all and allow all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple boolean logic:

```
r.Address.State == state || (state == null)

true || false -> true //(CA=CA)   ||(CA=null)
false|| true  -> true //(FL!=null)||(null=null)..null=null no matter the state from the database
false|| false -> false //(FL!=CA) ||(CA!=null)
```

Since in the second case, it is not checking against anything inside the database, then it will always return true for the `where` as it is more of a static check against the passed in parameter...thus why you get everything from the query.

I would assume that the purpose of this is so that the parameter acts like a filter only if supplied. If it is not supplied, then no filter is applied due to the `(null==null)`

In the second example, it is essentially doing the same thing as above. It is just not even building the static check into the LINQ.

It could just easily have been written as:

```
from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
where String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || 
    s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||                                       
    s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
select s;
```

Where, again, the check against the parameter will override any of the data checks because of boolean OR logic

Here is the first query written in a similar fashion as the second

```
var restaurants = from r in context.Restaurants
    select r;
if(state != null)
    restaurants = restaurants.Where(x=>x.Address.State == state);
```

[Here is a link to more on boolean logic](http://www.ithacalibrary.com/sp/subjects/boolean), there is actually plenty on this if you google it.

Comment: Why add more logic that is just overhead?  You could accomplish your linq query in a single query like what was asked.

Comment: @IyaTaisho I was merely explaining the logic and how they map back and forth so that the OP can better understand, which was the question

Answer (score 1):

In the first example: The || is an OR operator and the query would be what ever the state is OR if the state is null.  This doesnt necessarily mean that it willl return all records.  So the returns would be the state and those that are null.

the second example is is just checking to see whether there is search criteria to pull against.
Basically: 
if I have search criteria 
then get those records where the lastname contains the search criteria OR the firstname has the search criteria.

Make sense?  Your just trying to pull back records based on some sort of condition... maybe they wanted to have records that matched a certain state or was null... then perform some action upon them.